# How do I get my variables on a node in decision tree? I get Key Error 7

Tags: python, visualization, decision-tree

I am about to visualize a causal decision tree based on my model. I finally made it to actually plot the tree but somehow it doesnt show my variables names but `X[5]` on the nodes name. As soon as I add `feature_names=X` it does not plot anymore but shows `Key Error 7`
**
Can someone help out?
Many thanks
Elisa

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import graphviz
from econml.dml import CausalForestDML
from econml.cate_interpreter import SingleTreeCateInterpreter


#load cdv
data = pd.read_csv("Basis_Entscheidungsbaum.csv", sep=";", header=0)

#Variables 
feature_names=['DL', 'KE', 'AA', 'K', 'ST', 'G', 'BV', 'A']

Y = data['Z']
T = data['M']
X = data[feature_names]

#tree model
tree_model = CausalForestDML(n_estimators=1, subforest_size=1, inference=False, max_depth=4)

#causal decision tree
tree_model = tree_model.fit(Y=Y, X=X , T=T)
intrp = SingleTreeCateInterpreter(max_depth=3).interpret(tree_model, X)

#Visualization
intrp.plot(fontsize=12)

# intrp.plot(feature_names=X, fontsize=12)
```

I expect variables names on the node

**Input:**

| A | BV | G | ST | K | AA | KE | DL | Z | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 14 | 3400 | 1 | 0 | 7,49 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 29 | 5 | 2900 | 4 | 0 | 8,21 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 44 | 19 | 7400 | 5 | 2 | 9,39 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoring to `SingleTreeCateInterpreter`'s [documentation](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/_autosummary/econml.cate_interpreter.SingleTreeCateInterpreter.html#econml.cate_interpreter.SingleTreeCateInterpreter.plot), if you want the feature names, the method `plot` expects a list of strings:

> **plot**(ax=None, title=None, feature_names=None, treatment_names=None, max_depth=None, filled=True, rounded=True, precision=3, fontsize=None)
>
> - **feature_names** (list of str, optional) – Names of each of the features.

Since you already generated this list earlier, you can just pass it:

```
intrp.plot(feature_names=feature_names, fontsize=12)
```

### **Edit**

This is the code which I tried to reproduce the error but is running fine on my machine:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import graphviz
from econml.dml import CausalForestDML
from econml.cate_interpreter import SingleTreeCateInterpreter

%matplotlib inline

data = {
    'A': [32, 29, 44],
    'BV': [14, 5, 19],
    'G': [3400, 2900, 7400],
    'ST': [1, 4, 5],
    'K': [0, 0, 2],
    'AA': ['7,49', '8,21', '9,39'],
    'KE': [2, 0, 0],
    'DL': [3, 2, 4],
    'Z': [0, 1, 0],
    'M': [1, 1, 0]
}

# Replace decimal
data['AA'] = [float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in data['AA']]

# Define the number of additional rows to generate
n = 200

# Generate random values for each column and append to the data dictionary
for i in range(n):
    data['A'].append(np.random.randint(20, 50))
    data['BV'].append(np.random.randint(5, 20))
    data['G'].append(np.random.randint(2000, 8000))
    data['ST'].append(np.random.randint(1, 6))
    data['K'].append(np.random.randint(0, 3))
    data['AA'].append(round(np.random.uniform(5, 10),2))
    data['KE'].append(np.random.randint(0, 3))
    data['DL'].append(np.random.randint(2, 5))
    data['Z'].append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    data['M'].append(np.random.randint(0, 2))

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Variables 
feature_names=['DL', 'KE', 'AA', 'K', 'ST', 'G', 'BV', 'A']

Y = data['Z']
T = data['M']
X = data[feature_names]

#tree model
tree_model = CausalForestDML(n_estimators=1, subforest_size=1, inference=False, max_depth=4)

#causal decision tree
tree_model = tree_model.fit(Y=Y, X=X , T=T)
intrp = SingleTreeCateInterpreter(max_depth=3).interpret(tree_model, X)

#Visualization
intrp.plot(feature_names=feature_names, fontsize=12)
```

Output:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/aaa8Mh3]

### Edit 2

In order to avoid running into `InvalidParameterError: The 'criterion' parameter of DecisionTreeRegressor must be a str among {'poisson', 'squared_error', 'friedman_mse', 'absolute_error'}. Got 'mse' instead.`, you can use `sklearn<1.2`.

Comment: thanks for your input. 
this code (intrp.plot(feature_names=feature_names, fontsize=12)) unfortunately does not change the node names. It still shows up like X[1], X[2], X[3]...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jan for your support. I updated the post with a line of my code. Basically all variables stated with numeric input.

Comment: sure, please find them above.

Comment: @Elisa I want to rule out all other possible sources for the error. Are those decimals in your column `'AA'`? I mean is it 7.49 or 7,490 i.e. almost 7.5k? If it is a decimal, maybe you should set the parameter `decimal=','` within `read_csv()`

Comment: i don't really run into an error either. It's just that it does not name the nodes the right way. As soon as the tree plots, I don't get a node called "AA" but rather a node called "X[5]".

Comment: Thanks for your 2nd comment, too. Its a decimal number and I´ll integrate it :-)

Comment: @Elisa Ok, thanks for the clarification. The code in my answer produces nodes with the correct feture names. Can you try to run it and check if you get the correct feature names, too?

Comment: @Jan great you managed it to get the right output!!
As you're using`%matplotlib inline` I also switched from Spyder to Jupiter Notebook. Somehow I get this error according

`InvalidParameterError: The 'criterion' parameter of DecisionTreeRegressor must be a str among {'poisson', 'squared_error', 'friedman_mse', 'absolute_error'}. Got 'mse' instead.`

wich refers to 

`intrp = SingleTreeCateInterpreter(max_depth=3).interpret(tree_model, X)`

Comment: @Elisa I run sklearn verion 1.1.3 and I just get the warning `Criterion 'mse' was deprecated in v1.0 and will be removed in version 1.2. Use criterion='squared_error' which is equivalent.` Seems like you are running sklearn version >= 1.2. Consider downgrading sklearn maybe

Comment: Genius! It works perfectly! :-)